# Error with Authlogic version 2.1.6 on jruby

Tags: ruby, jruby

I am getting an error with authlogic version 2.1.6 with jruby1.6.6
running on ruby 1.9.

Following is the stacktrace of the error:

: couldn't parse YAML at line 17 column 13
Psych::SyntaxError (: couldn't parse YAML at line 17 column
13):
  org/jruby/ext/psych/PsychParser.java:270:in `parse'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.6/lib/ruby/1.9/psych.rb:148:in`
parse_stream'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.6/lib/ruby/1.9/psych.rb:119:in `parse'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.6/lib/ruby/1.9/psych.rb:106:in`load'
  org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1700:in `__send__'
  org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2099:in`send'
  org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1614:in `each'
  authlogic (2.1.6) lib/authlogic/i18n/translator.rb:8:in`translate'
  authlogic (2.1.6) lib/authlogic/i18n.rb:78:in `translate'

Any Pointers on this would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

There have been reports of this (e.g., http://bugs.jruby.org/6415). The problem is that of encoding. While the root cause is still unresolved, most likely you can get around your particular problem by enforcing UTF-8 encoding on the input. That is,

```
jruby -U -S gem install authlogic
```

Hope this helps.